# Any gotchas using sfdx force:package:version:create --skipvalidation?

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, packaging-2

Using `sfdx force:limits:api:display`, our results include:

```
NAME                                         REMAINING  MAXIMUM
───────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────  ─────────
Package2VersionCreates                       6          6
Package2VersionCreatesWithoutValidation      500        500
```

that suggest that the "without validation" is what we need to use for Continuous Integration (CI) builds as we have multiple packages.

This [Skip Validation to Quickly Iterate Package Development](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_skip_validation.htm) explains:

> Iterate package development more efficiently by skipping validation of
>   dependencies, package ancestors, and metadata during package version
>   creation. You can use the skip validation parameter with
>   second-generation managed packages and unlocked packages. Skipping
>   validation reduces the time it takes to create a new package version,
>   but package versions created without validation can’t be promoted to
>   the released state.

so it sounds like you could get a false sense of security about your package.

If you have used this in practice, what has your experience been?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great option for CI builds.

In CI, I could use this step to create a package version, then install it to a new scratch org and run tests there or do something else.

I started used this today.

I don't think it might get a false sense of security. If there are any problems, they can be discovered with a package install.

I think I will use skip validation options for every CI build except for a minor or a major version build.